# Problem with Anaconda Uninstall/Install (MacOS)

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

I accidentally deleted Anaconda app by removing it into the bin (and I emptied it). And I redownloaded the anaconda3 pkg in an attempt to reinstall the application but it doesn't allow me to reinstall stating that Anaconda3 is already in /opt/anaconda3. And I am not sure what I can do to reinstall it.

Does anyone know what I can do?
I also downloaded the anaconda clean package using Terminal and all, but it doesn't seem to work still. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal type

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Scroll to the bottom of the page and add

```
export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm then run this command

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and then this one

```
conda install anaconda-navigator
```